# Static files in Django with AWS S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just moved the static files of my Django project into AWS S3. It works so far. But my .css files contain relative paths, for example to fonts, for example:

```
@import "variables";

@font-face {
  font-family: '#{$font-family}';
  src:  url('#{$font-path}/#{$font-family}.eot?4zay6m');
  format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

My browser console shows that the path to these file is set correctly, for example

`https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/plugins/fonts/myfont.ttf?4zay6m`

but I get a permission denied, because unlike the other (from django set paths), these paths do not contain the "Amazon stuff" after the question mark like

`https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/jquery.tablednd.js?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXX`

Is there a simple workaroud?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do solve your problem using :

1. Set S3 bucket as static web hosting: Bucket -> Properties -> Static website hosting -> Set root file and error file as index.html
2. Use public end point as URL to access your content like css, js or images

**Your S3 is not public static hosting to access without Access token of AWS account.**

For example how to do S3 bucket as hosting see this blog : https://www.internetkatta.com/host-angular-2-or-4-or-5-version-in-aws-s3-using-cloudfront